# How do those "Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information" things work?

Tags: support

I often see comments under answers like:

> Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center. (Community Bot)

I'm assuming I don't have permission to add those comments to low-quality answers myself. Who can create those comments? What is the best way to flag answers in clear need of citations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two [review queues](https://english.stackexchange.com/review), First Answers and First Questions (unlocked at 500 reputation), have an option to share feedback attributed to "Community" on the post. These queues may not have very many posts in them because it only takes one person to finish the review. For this reason especially, you need to make sure you're choosing the right options when reviewing — "Share Feedback" isn't a substitute for a downvote or a flag or a close vote! It just leaves a comment and removes the post from the queue.

(The queues Late Answers and Low Quality Posts also leave comments, but not by "Community".)

From the [announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013/323179) (note: as a non-code site we don't have all these choices):

[image: dialogue with four comment options]

If you're not doing a review, you can leave specific feedback using comments yourself. To make this easier, there are some [AutoReviewComments userscripts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/379977/323179) that were developed by other members of the Stack Exchange community. Still, try to leave customized comments where you can; it is not very obvious how someone can add "citations or documentation" for something they intuitively know just from speaking the language, for example.

Comment: Thanks! I do wish there was a way of doing this on non-first answers, just to avoid having to retype it.

Comment: @alphabet Userscripts can help with that. (See edit)

Answer (score 1):

*I'm assuming I don't have permission to add those comments to low-quality answers myself.*

Actually, I think you can. Except for formatting and making poor questions ore acceptable, users rarely edit other users’ posts. But it’s possible to do so.

I find the bot comment unpleasant and often overused.